# HoloLens Emulator error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I'm trying to launch a very simple HoloLens app - "Origami", from the first HoloLens tutorial ( https://developer.microsoft.com/EN-US/WINDOWS/HOLOGRAPHIC/holograms_101e ).

But, when I'm launching it in HoloLens emulator, I see the message "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**"

[image]

I reinstalled the Unity, Visual Studio and Hololens Emulator, but I see the same result.

Though, when I launched just reinstalled Unity, I saw the same list of recently created Unity projects, as before reinstallation. It makes me think that maybe there was some parts of software I didn't remove.

I would be really gratefull for your advice and step-by-step explanation if possible.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does it say next to the green Play arrow ? It should say emulator but you may have device or else.

Comment: @Everts It is HoloLens Emulator

Comment: @Everts I also set mode to Release, x86

Comment: What version of the emulator is it?  10.0.14393.0?  What version of Unity did you install?  5.5.0b1?  Does the HoloLens Emulator actually start when you launch out of Visual Studio?